# Display current time with momentjs

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, momentjs

I am trying to create a clock component that shows current time dynamically.

> **Problem:** Time is shown as expected on load (**HH:mm A**), but the clock does not change at all.

**clock.component.ts :**

```
import {
    ChangeDetectionStrategy,
    Component,
    OnInit
} from "@angular/core";
import { Observable, interval } from "rxjs";
import { map, distinctUntilChanged } from "rxjs/operators";
import * as moment from "moment";

@Component({
    selector: "app-clock",
    templateUrl: "./clock.component.html",
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ClockComponent implements OnInit {

    pageLoaded: moment.Moment;
    time: Observable<string>;

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.pageLoaded = moment(new Date());

        this.time = interval(1000).pipe(
            map(() => this.pageLoaded.format("HH:mm A")),
            distinctUntilChanged()
        );
    }
}
```

**clock.component.html :**

```
<div>{{ time | async }}</div>
```

Comment: The clock doesn't change because you redraw the same Moment instance every time. If you want a new value, you should create a new Moment instance (also, you don't need to call it with a date, calling it without any argument gives the current time). And as you might have noticed, the clock on the Moment homepage is also dynamic, so you could [take a look at their code](https://github.com/moment/momentjs.com/blob/8b3956c87bb870e8e53a6245e2a2e231acfbbef3/assets/js/core-home.js#L96) to find out how they did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if I where you I'll use `@types/moment` to make my life easier (optional).

So, why 'the clock does not change at all'?

cause you initialized the value of the clock once the page load and this value won't update so basically `this.time` holds the initialized value, not the updated value, so, the following is the same as your `component` but with a little edition.

```
import {
    ChangeDetectionStrategy,
    Component,
    OnInit
} from "@angular/core";
import { Observable, interval } from "rxjs";
import { map, distinctUntilChanged } from "rxjs/operators";
import moment, { Moment } from "moment"; // using @types/moment

@Component({
    selector: "app-clock",
    templateUrl: "./clock.component.html",
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ClockComponent implements OnInit {

    pageLoaded: Moment;
    time: Observable<string>;

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {
    this.time = interval(1000*60).pipe( // why you need 1s interval with HH:mm time format simply update it every minute not every second.
      map(() => {
        this.pageLoaded = moment(new Date()); // you need the value of now not the value of the initialized time.
        return this.pageLoaded.format("HH:mm A");
      })
    );
  }
}
```

and your view just as it is.

Here is an stackblitz example check it yourself https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-moment-rxjs

Comment: That did it, thank You for the help! I just can't seem to import **moment** in an appropriate manner, when I import it as you described, it underlines the initial **moment** pointer. When I use it with the " * " , it works.

Comment: To import moment the way I described you have to install `@types/moment` first, run `npm i -D @types/moment`.

Comment: I get the following output when installing: ** npm WARN deprecated @types/moment@2.13.0: This is a stub types definition for Moment (https://github.com/moment/moment). Moment provides its own type definitions, so you don't need @types/moment installed!  **

Comment: As the message says they have their own types definition build-in so you don't have to install the external package anymore.